# Anki plugin to transform folder of images into deck of picture + picture filename

Tags: flashcard, anki

I have a folder with 1000 images of dishes:

- `ratatouille.jpg` is an image of [ratatouille](https://www.google.com/search?q=ratatouille&hl=en&tbm=isch)
- `mori soba.jpg` is an image of [mori soba](https://www.google.com/search?q=mori%20soba&hl=en&tbm=isch)
- etc

I want to make an Anki flashcards deck to memorize all the names of the dishes.
The deck should show me the picture as a question, and show me the dish name as an answer.
Is there any Anki plugin that can do that?

Requirements:

- Any platform is OK
- Free, ideally open source
- on-premise (not a webapp)
- plugin or standalone program or script

Comment: Do you care if it is actually a plugin or is an external program fine? I presume since Anki is cross-platform that this should be too right?

Comment: @NickWilde: external program is fine too! Edited.

Comment: Can't you just code them using a LaTeX file?

Comment: @VicAche: I am not sure how LaTeX would help here, but feel free to develop the idea in an answer, thanks!

Comment: It has been a year. Have you found your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to use the Anki plugin [Media Import](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1531997860).

It takes all files in a folder, and makes each file into a note with the filename and the image or sound within the file.

Fields are configurable. New notes are put into a special deck, so after importing you can just move them where you want.

[image: Anki media importer]

Comment: Can this add the image to the already existed deck? I have a deck of GRE vocab and would like to add images to the back of the cards

Comment: @Ooker: You should ask about this as a new question, as it is a different usage.

Comment: well, I just ask if this addon has this feature or not. I think asking a new question might be too much for this